# Call method after ear start

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, ear

I need to run ejb component and call a `method` after start application as early as possible. Does anyone know best solution, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming it's a EJB application, in that case you can use [singleton session bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html), it can be used for application initialization in a portable, vendor-independent way.

And if it's a Web application then you need to use [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)

Comment: Ok, but how can I start it as first? For testing I want to write log "Start app".

Comment: you need to use @Startup annotation on the EJB

Answer (score 1):

If you're using EJB 3.1, you can use `@Singleton` and `@Startup` as described in [this blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/application_startup_shutdown_callbacks).

If you're using older versions of the specification, a common way to achieve this is to register a `ServletContextListener` that does the initialization you want. This obviously requires to to create a war within your ear, if you don't have it already.